# Cloudformation: create aws security group referencing another security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

I would like to create an rds security group allowing all access from another security group.  I know this is possible in the web ui consul by selecting `custom` as the source type and then entering the security group id in place of an ip address range.  Here is an example of what im attempting to use at the moment:

```
"SgRds2Ec2SecurityGroup": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
  "Properties": {
    "GroupDescription": "rds access from corp",
    "VpcId": {
      "Ref": "VpcId"
    },
    "SecurityGroupIngress": [
      {
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "FromPort": "0",
        "ToPort": "65535",
        "SecurityGroupID": {
          "Ref": "SgRdsEc2SecurityGroup"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This gives me the error:

```
2018-01-22 18:48:47 UTC   SgRds2Ec2SecurityGroup   CREATE_FAILED        Encountered unsupported property SecurityGroupID
```

What should I use in place of `SecurityGroupID`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-rule.html) you're looking for `SourceSecurityGroupId`.

```
"SecurityGroupIngress": [
  {
    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
    "FromPort": "0",
    "ToPort": "65535",
    "SourceSecurityGroupId": {
      "Ref": "SgRdsEc2SecurityGroup"
    }
  }
]
```